# How to read output from ostream?

Tags: c++

[SOLUTION]

You can pass a stringstream into the paramater that takes an ostream. After that you can get the text that was set inside the stringstream by its str() funktion.

```
#include <sstream>

...

{
stringstream ss;
print(ss);
string text;
text = ss.str();
// Handle text
}
```

Given there's a function like this:

```
void print(ostream& stream) const;
```

How can I access the data that is written into the ostream?

I was thinking of interpreting it as a string:

```
string text;
print( text );
// Interpret text
```

The reason is there's another function that has a pointer to an object as a parameter:

```
void append( *Data data );
```

And I must use the data objects print method to get at its data:

```
// This is a public function in the Data class
void append( *Data data ) {
    string text;
    data->print( text );
    // append data to this Data object
}
```

I was trying to cast to a stringstream but that didn't work. I'm thinking if I could save the data to a file and then read it as workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of this...

```
string text;
print( text );
```

...try this...

```
ostringstream text;
print( text );
```

Then you can use the text written into "text".

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't spit any error but how can I convert the ostringstream to a string? the << operator doesn't work. neither does the ostringstreams str member and niether any combination of get or getline().

Comment: @user1356190: how were you trying to use the `str()` member function?  Will work ala `std::cout << text.str() << '\n';`

Comment: Oh I didn't realize it had a str() _function_! Looking at the link [link]http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/ it doesn't say anywhere. Anyway, I passed a stringstream as the paramater for ostream and then I converted it into a string with "text = ss.str()". It works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @user1356190: You're welcome. BTW - `ostream` is the base class - modelling any output stream, many of which don't keep a record of their output as it's sent to a network or device and no longer needed locally. `ostream` doesn't have a `str()` member function. The derived class `ostringstream` adds one though - it exists precisely to let you capture stream output in a `string`.  Because `print()` accepts an `ostream` by reference, any derived class can be passed in and work polymorphically.